# CUDA memory (type) for device only calculation during kernel calls (compute 1.1 or 1.2)

Tags: c++, c, memory, cuda

I'm currently learning CUDA and my algorithm has to do some heavy calculations based on some input data. Those calculations are made in a loop that spins up to 1024 rounds. Everything works fine as long as I have a small number of threads (< 100´000) per kernel, but if I want to utilize more threads, the kernel will be interrupted by windows as it takes too long to complete.

My solution would be to split up the heavy calculations in several kernel calls:

1. The **main** kernel, that prepares the input data and calculates the first x rounds (loop unrolled). This will only be called once per input.
2. The **work** kernel, that does the next x rounds (loop unrolled). This will be called as often as required to calculate all required rounds.

Between each kernel call (one *main*, many *work*), I have to save 16 + length bytes of data, that will be used on the next call (length is the length of the input, it is fixed per *main* call). The *main* kernel will initial write those bytes and the *work* kernel will read them, run the next calculations and writes the original data with the new result.
I only need those data on the device, no host access is required. Which kind of memory do I have to use for this? At least it must be global memory as it is the only writable memory that is persistend during kernel calls, isn't it? But then, what? 
Could you give me an advice on how I have to proceed to work with the correct memory (and best performance)?

In 'pseudocode' it could look like this:

```
prepare memory to hold threads * (16 + length) bytes

for length = 1 to x step 1
  call mainKernel
  rounds = 1024 - rounds_done_in_main
  for rounds to 0 step rounds_done_in_work
    call workKernel
  end for
end for

cleanup memory

--------

template <unsigned char length> __global__ mainKernel() {
  unsigned char input[length];
  unsigned char output[16];
  const int tid = ...;

  devPrepareInput<length>(input);

  calc round 1: doSomething<length>(output, input)
  calc round 2: doSomething<length>(output, output + input) // '+' == append

  write data to memory based on tid // data == output + input
}

template <unsigned char length, remaining rounds> __global__ workKernel() {
  unsigned char *input;
  unsigned char *output;
  const int tid = ...;

  read data from memory based on tid
  ouput = data
  input = data+16

  if rounds >= 1
    calc round x  : doSomething<length>(output, output + input)
  if rounds >= 2
    calc round x+1: doSomething<length>(output, output + input) // '+' == append

  if rounds == x // x is the number of rounds in the last work call
    do final steps on output
  else
    write ouput + input to memory based on tid (for next call)
}
```

Comment: If you have enough blocks, it is far easier to just reduce the grid size and launch the kernel multiple times, adding the appropriate offset to the block number inside the kernel.

Comment: It is going to be pretty hard to make recommendations about performance when all you can offer is pseudocode containing a lot of template instantiations of "do something". Can you be a bit more concrete in what you are really wanting to know?

Comment: The code at all doesn't matter at all and it would be too bug to post here. I was asking about what I have to do / what kind of device memory I can use to save data between kernel calls (The lines with read data / write data). The performance was related to that memory.

Comment: If kernel timeout is really a problem, you might seriously consider running it on a non-display-attached GPU to avoid the timeout. Otherwise I would seriously consider tera's suggestion, unless there are dependencies between threads that prevent it. Otherwise you may be unnecessarily bandwidth bottlenecked.

Comment: OK, I will try to reduce the grid size. But independent of the grid size, is there any possibility in doing this using device memory. When yes, how? As I'm in the learning process, it would be nice to know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with device memory.  A variable declared with `__device__` provides a static declaration of a buffer that can be used directly by kernels, without requiring any `cudaMemcpy` operations, nor requiring that the pointer be passed explicitly to the kernel. Since it has the [lifetime of the application](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-variable-qualifier), the data in it will persist from one kernel call to the next.

```
#define NUM_THREADS 1024
#define DATA_PER_THREAD 16
__device__ int temp_data[NUM_THREADS*DATA_PER_THREAD];

__global__ my_kernel1(...){
  int my_data[DATA_PER_THREAD] = {0};
  int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
  // perform calculations

  // write out temp data
  for (int i = 0; i < DATA_PER_THREAD; i++) temp_data[i + (idx * DATA_PER_THREAD)] = my_data[i];
  }

__global__ my_kernel2(...){
  int my_data[DATA_PER_THREAD];
  // read in temp data
  for (int i = 0; i < DATA_PER_THREAD; i++) my_data[i] = temp_data[i + (idx * DATA_PER_THREAD)];
  // perform calculations

  }
```

There are a variety of ways you could optimize this based on your usage pattern within the kernel.  The transfer of data to/from `my_data` is not really necessary.  Obviously your kernel code could just access `temp_data` directly in place of `my_data`, with appropriate indexing.

If you did decide to load/store it, you could interleave the data to allow for coalesced access during the `for`-loop reading and writing of the data.